# Endless struggle with Visual Studio and code signing

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, code-signing

After months of several failures, few hundred certificate request and burned nerves I think that it’s time call for help.

Our organization has a valid Active Directory Certificate Authority implementation and we want to use it to use it for code signing. I’ve tried different versions of modified certificate templates and requests. Certificate issuing works fine (all certificate request, issuing and importing are done via PowerShell scripts). We are trying to import those certificates via Developer Command prompt and Visual Studio but with no success.

Can Visual studio work with certificates issued by our own CA or is that a problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have the private key for that certificate and what are the properties of that certificate? Without that basic info no answer could be provided.

Comment: We have our own CA, so we can generate certificate and have private key as we want.